# Directly echo the resulting data show an error msg

Tags: php, mysqli

When I am echo the `$result` variable. It display an error msg like this:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in D:\Inspiration\server\Table2_yahooData_db.php
>   on line 13

```
<?php
// connect to the dataBase
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'yahooData');

//checking Connection.
if (!$conn) {
    die('Error connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
}

// Creating select query Using sql commands.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM User;" ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo $result;

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM User";` . No need of ;

Comment: you can not echo $result intead do if($result){echo "something"}

Comment: I want to show what value does $result hold. #sky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result` is an object.

You cannot print it with string's `echo` function.

You can rather print it with `print_r($result);`

`echo` is for scalar variables (which have single value or are single dimensions) like number, string. For multi-dimensional variables e.g. array, objects we need to use `print_r()` which prints the whole tree.

Comment: why i can't print $result variable use echo.?
yup print_r function print the $result variable.

Comment: `echo` is for scalar variables (which have single value or are single dimensions) like number, string. For multi-dimensional variables e.g. array, objects we need to use `print_r()` which prints the whole tree).

Answer (score 1):

When using a `SELECT` query the [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function returns a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), not a string. You need to use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to put the results into an array. Here is an object-oriented example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT name FROM User";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['name'];
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```